# Python Qt QListWidget Double Clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qlistwidget

I want to add double clicked attribute for my QListWidget objects.

My command line does not work:

```
   self.connect(self.listWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemDoubleClicked(QtGui.QListWidgetItem)"), self.showItem)
```

How to add double clicked  attribute ? How to give object parameter to QtCore.SIGNAL.

Answer (score 10):

The reason why the signal connection did not work, is that you are using the wrong signature for [QListWidget.itemDoubleClicked](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlistwidget.html#itemDoubleClicked). It should instead look like this:

```
self.connect(self.listWidget,
             QtCore.SIGNAL("itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *)"),
             self.showItem)
```

However, I would advise that you avoid using this method of connecting signals altogther, and switch to the [new-style syntax](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html) instead. This would allow you to rewrite the above code like this:

```
self.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.showItem)
```

Which is not only simpler and cleaner, but also much less error-prone (in fact, an exception will be raised if the wrong signal name/signature is used).